# Reading Excel fails using for loops multithreading

Tags: excel, vb.net, loops

I would like to loop through the columns and rows of an excel spreadsheet and put the values into a list. The spreadsheet is 70 columns and 850+ rows. No matter what I try it fails to loop through a 2nd time. It actually jumps out of the sub routine all together. Weirdly it doesn't error out, which makes it really hard. The spreadsheet cells can contain anything from formulas to static text, numbers, etc. I'm not sure if that matters or helps. I am so frazzled at this point that I hope I make sense. I can post more info if you need it. Any ideas?

Ps. My code has commented lines of failed attempts. I hope that helps show what I've tried.

```
Private Sub GetSpreadsheetList(ByVal HeaderRowIndex As Integer)
    g_SpreadsheetList = New List(Of ListOfValuePair)
    Try
        Dim XlSh As Excel.Worksheet = Xlbook.ActiveSheet
        'Dim LastRowIndex As Long = XlSh.Range("A4000").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row + 1
        'Dim LastColIndex As Long = XlSh.Range(ToolBox.RemoveCharAndSpaces("AAA" & Str(HeaderRowIndex), True)).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Dim LastRowIndex As Long = XlSh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Dim LastColIndex As Long = XlSh.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Dim Cntr As Integer = 1

        For ColIndex As Integer = 1 To LastColIndex
            Dim NewFNO As New ListOfValuePair
            For RowIndex As Integer = HeaderRowIndex To LastRowIndex ' - HeaderRowIndex

                If RowIndex = HeaderRowIndex Then
                    Dim XlRange As Excel.Range = CType(XlSh.Cells(RowIndex, ColIndex), Excel.Range)
                    'Dim CellVal As String = RemoveCharAndSpaces(CType(XlRange.Text, String))

                    'Dim CellVal As String = "Tito's"


                    'NewFNO.Key = CellVal
                    NewFNO.Key = XlRange.Text.ToString

                ElseIf RowIndex > HeaderRowIndex Then
                    'Dim XlRange As Excel.Range = CType(XlSh.Cells(RowIndex, ColIndex), Excel.Range)
                    'Dim XlObj As Object = XlSh.Cells(RowIndex, ColIndex)
                    'Dim CellVal As String = CType(XlRange.Text, String)

                    'Dim CellVal As String = "String Taco"
                    'Try : CellVal = RemoveCharAndSpaces(CType(XlRange.Text, String))
                    'Catch ex As Exception : CellVal = "ERROR VAL" : End Try
                    'MessageBox.Show(CellVal & vbNewLine & "Column: " & ColIndex & " | Row: " & RowIndex)

                    'NewFNO.ListOfValues.Add(CellVal)
                    NewFNO.ListOfValues.Add(XlSh.Cells(RowIndex, ColIndex).Value2)


                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Faillure!!!")
                End If
            Next
            g_SpreadsheetList.Add(NewFNO)
        Next
        Stop
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Modules | Column_Compare_Family_Table | GetSpreadsheetList" & vbNewLine & "Problems getting spreadsheet cell values.", "Error!")
    End Try
End Sub
```

**Edit
This program has many threads, and many global variables. The memory being used during debugging shows 102(MB). That seems like a lot so I copy and pasted this code into a different solution. It worked like it should. Could memory be an issue here?

**Edit 2
Since the code worked in a different solution, I tried running the original solution again but without initiating a new thread. It worked! So I don't think the code or excel. I think it has something to do with the thread.

Comment: Baby steps...  Can you do a minimal loop through  the sheet like `Dim Cell as Range; For Each Cell in ActiveSheet.UsedRange; msgBox Cell.Value2; Next Cell;`  ?

Comment: Another tack to consider maybe.  You can query Excel spreadsheets via ODBC giving you a DataTable object to work with, or maybe one of the many existing Excel  libraries available any of which save you the heavy lifting

Comment: @ChrisMaurer : No. It will popup the first messagebox and then exit the sub.

Comment: @Hursey : Before your comment, I never heard of Open Database Connectivity. Will you show me how you would use it to read the spreadsheet?

Comment: If you look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/transfer-data-to-excel-from-vb, there is a section for Transfer data to a worksheet by using ADO.  Plus plenty of resources out on the internet

Comment: @Hursey I think you mean OleDb with the excel extension.

Comment: Do you have a class called ListOfValuePair?

Comment: LastRowIndex and LastColIndex must both be Integer not Long.

Comment: If you use VSTO (please confirm?), you should know that the Excel Object Model is not thread safe: it only supports calls via the main thread (aka the UI thread). Any calls under another thread may generate COM exceptions or (worst) unstable behaviours. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/threading-support-in-office?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using VSTO, you can do: `Xlbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value` which will return a 2D array of the values within range.
Not only this is fast, but also you then do not need to worry about Excel any more: work on your 2D array.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value?view=excel-pia

If you do not specify `RangeValueDataType` then

> If the specified Range object is empty, returns the value Empty (use the IsEmpty function to test for this case). If the Range object contains more than one cell, returns an array of values (use the IsArray function to test for this case)

Comment: Your advice sounds good. I am trying but with failure. I am getting a castexception. It can't cast type 'System.String' to type 'System.String[]'. The code that I tried is: `Dim ScrubbedRange() As String = XlSh.UsedRange.Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)`. Do you see where I went wrong?

Comment: You set `RangeValueDataType` to XMLSpreadsheet, which means you get a unique string which contains the XML of the range. But you defined the style as a string array; hence the inability to cast.

Comment: You should either not specify `RangeValueDataType` and by default will get an array of objects, or use a library to work with the XML, which is great if you need to extract formatting or formula, but not very useful if all you are looking for at the values. Also, in your question you used `.text`, which returns what each cell currently displays; I do not recommend using this property because it might be affected if you change the column width, or change the Cell formatting.

Comment: ** Answer: This was a threading issue and order of operations. Thank you everyone for your help.